# Several SecurityContexts in one HttpSession

Tags: authentication, spring-security, httpsession, pre-authentication, security-context

I have been working on application that is using spring security. I am quite new to spring security and ended up with problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664893/how-to-manually-set-an-authenticated-user-in-spring-security-springmvc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824395/spring-security-forward-directive-cant-forward-to-login-form/). But it is a bit different.

I do manual authentication this way:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
Authentication authentication = this.authenticationProvider.authenticate(token);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

When the page loads everything seems OK. But, when I navigate around application it seems that I loose my SecurityContext. (I have status bar showing user name if user is logged in)

I get my context this way:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
```

What is more the context is not lost entirely sometimes it loads correctly, after some incorrect loads. It seems that I have several contexts in one session ( I have HttpSessionListener and sessionCreated fires only once). I tried printing out context's objects hashes and noticed that there
 are several different hashes repeating. Only one is with my connected user the others are not.

So I assume that there are several context's in one session (if this is even possible). 
I hope I explained everything clearly. 
I would be grateful if anybody could provide me with some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i did it! **Marcel Stör** answer did help me to look for correct keewords and so on. Thank you.

The problem was that I was setting SecurityContext in bean that was not aware of Security filter chain. It was called on @PostConstruct and it was not right.

What I really needed was **PRE_AUTH_FILTER** and proper Spring security configuration. So PRE_AUTH_FILTER is in SpringSecurity filter chain puts authentication object correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're doing the context needs to be bound to the current thread. Because, when you call

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
```

the context from a `ThreadLocal` store is returned. Make sure the context is bound to your current thread *with each request* (can't tell more as you don't describe how you're doing that).

Comment: Thanks, now I, at least, have something to hold on to. I am still not sure how to fix this. _"Make sure the context is bound to your current thread with each request (can't tell more as you don't describe how you're doing that)."_ Problem is that I am not doing this. I thought spring takes care of that. What do you want me to describe more.

Comment: @VytautasAlkimavičius, "I thought spring takes care of that." - yes, Spring _does_ take care of that, given it is setup properly. Your question includes no hints as for what Spring config/infrastructure you have in place.