# Manually create first user in app using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I inherited an app that controls access and editing of a small database.  It uses Spring Security for auth.  It uses a local table for users and roles.

The app provides an interface to create new users, if you have role ROLE_ADMIN.  Inside the method for creating the user is a block of code like this:

```
    Authentication authentication =SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    accountService.createUser(getUserDetails(newUser,password,authentication),role,fullname, displayName);
```

I have to create new instances of this app with slightly configuration, and an empty database (except for static data).  That means the user table is empty.  I can only create new users if I can log in (the story about how they got the app running in the first place is confusing).

So, I defined a new bean with a `@Component` annotation and a `@PostConstruct` method which does this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    List<UserInfo>  currentUserList = userAccountService.getCurrentUserList();
    if (currentUserList.isEmpty()) {
        Authentication  authentication  = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User    user    = new User("admin", "admin", true, true, true, true, authentication.getAuthorities());
        userAccountService.createUser(user, EstimationConstants.ROLE_ADMIN, "admin", "admin");
    }
}
```

When this runs, it gets a NPE because "authentication" is null.  I imagine that's because it's not running as a logged-in user in the context.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Instead of calling `authentication.getAuthorities()` can you not set some _default authorities_ you'd like to have?

Comment: I managed to figure this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824395/spring-security-forward-directive-cant-forward-to-login-form/7972971#7972971 . I'll fill in the solution details later.

Comment: @Morfic I only noticed this comment now. I don't really understand the choices or the effective difference.

Comment: Since this is a _"one time `userless` execution"_, remove the part related to the authentication data, and just go `new User("admin", "admin", true, true, true, true, Arrays.asList(ADMIN, DEV_OPS, etc))`. Makes it pretty straight forward and easy to understand the intention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key code to get a valid security context was the following:

```
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(EstimationConstants.ROLE_ADMIN));
        Authentication  authentication  = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password, authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you put the authorities directly in your `@Post` method instead of relying on `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()`? As it is now it's somewhat "_hidden_", difficult for someone new to immediately understand where the authorities are provisioned.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: The code you posted as the answer, where does it belong to, and how does it relate to the `@PostConstruct` method from the question?

Comment: It goes in the same method, effectively replacing the line that creates the "authentication" object.