# Combine username/password login with certificate in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, certificate

I'm developing a webapp with Spring MVC, I use Spring Security and have already written the code for username/password login and it works. Now I have to write the code to allow users to log in with a certificate... I read data from a cardreader and process it and then I create a UserDetails object, then a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and load it to Spring security context like this:

```
UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(usuario.getCodUsuario());

Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Then I redirect the user to a view, and he can see the menu parts that he's supposed to according to his credentials, but when he clicks an option, suddenly Spring Security throws a "not authenticated" exception...

EDIT: here's my Spring Security config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd>

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/login" security="none" />
<http pattern="/firma" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login?loginError"/>
<logout logout-url="/logout"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="UserPasswordAuthenticationProvider" class="es.mywebapp.common.security.UserPasswordAuthenticationProvider"/>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider ref="UserPasswordAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And the exception goes like this:

```
DEBUG Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that you assign the authentication token to the SecurityContextHolder. But it seems like the SecurityContextHolder is not attached to any Session. So when the ThreadLocal closes the SecurityContextHolder is lost. (This is an assumption which i can not verify with the information available. You need to update the question or check for yourself
You have to attach the `SecurityContext` to the Session:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

// Create a new session and add the security context.
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
```

If the `SecurityContextHolder` is created in a setting where it is part of the web context/ session Spring should handle attaching it to and retrieving it from the session via the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`. So if this is the case you should not employ the first solution but rather check the configuration of your `FilterChain`.

Link elaborating on **attaching the SecurityContextHolder to the Session**: [How to manually set an authenticated user in Spring Security / SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664893/how-to-manually-set-an-authenticated-user-in-spring-security-springmvc)

Link elaborating on the **SecurityContextHolder in the light of a web application** (see section 5.4): http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html