# Spring security Authentication object in init lazy beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I´m implementing Spring security with `Roles` into the `Authentication` object, to be used to limit the access in my services though the `@Secure("ROLE")` annotation.
Everything seems works fine, and for not good authentication Roles Spring Security throw `Access Denied Exception`.

My problem arrive in my Integration tests, because I´m using some init lazy beans in order to load some information previous the tests starts, and in that moment when I´m trying to access to this limited services I receive the `Access denied exception.`
In my Unit Test I achieve resolve the same issue, and use some services with the secure annotation creating the `Authentication` object, and adding into `SpringContextHolder`.

```
  List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ADMIN_ROLE");
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("test@test.com", "test", authorities);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

But when I startup my Jetty Server for the integration test, and my init lazy beans are running and run this code, the situation does not works like in the unit test, and Spring throw me the `Access denied exception` because cannot find any `Authentication` object in the `SecurityContext`.

Somebody can help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attah the SecurityContext to the session. Since it is Threadbound it will otherwise be lost for future use. See the following Answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16778652/2319179

Answer (score 0):

I discover that using @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER_ROLE')") is working during the init lazy bans run. So I can avoid have to add the SecurityContext in my session. Abd thanks the lord becuase the init lazy bean is not a Servlet so was imposible made what you propose