# Spring form login: how to put user profile into SecurityContextHolder from a controller

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a page for user to type in username/password and choose user `role`. User may or may not exist at the moment but I have to custom code to register the user from `controller` by information from the page.

The question is, how can I put the user `role` into the Security context after register or validate the user so that spring framework can identify user role across the application, like in `SecurityContextHolder`?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664893/how-to-manually-set-an-authenticated-user-in-spring-security-springmvc

Answer (score 0):

To get the role assigned for user that want's to log in you need to implement `UserDetailsService` or write a custom `AuthenticationProvider` class that handles the authentication. Both of them have an authenticate method that needs 3 parameters: username, password and collection of authorities. Read up on google how to implement custom UserDetailsService or AuthenticationProvider.