# Spring security : auto login issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

i am trying to auto login user after signup. Here is code for auto login

```
private boolean autoLogin(HttpServletRequest request, User user) {

    SimpleGrantedAuthority auth = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN");
    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(auth);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);

    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
    authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);

    return true;
}
```

and inside an interceptor that check logged in user code is

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Problem is when i debug the code (after auto login) the principal object has logged in user's email address instead of UserDetails object.

Things working fine when i log in useing spring security login form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664893/how-to-manually-set-an-authenticated-user-in-spring-security-springmvc?rq=1 i found my answer here

Answer (score 0):

You're missing re-assigning the return from `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()`.

This line:

```
authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
```

should be:

```
token = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
```

That should fix things.