# Spring Security Authenicate User in Registration

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-security

I want add a guest user with Ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : restUrlUser + "/front/saveGuestUser",
                    success : function(res) {
                        if (res)
                            return res.id
                    }
                });
```

and in the controller i get the request with this method :

```
@RequestMapping("/front/saveGuestUser")
@ResponseBody
public Long saveGuestUser() {
    return iUserService.saveGuestUser();
}
```

and the in service layer i use the SecurityContextHolder and add the user into it :

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public User saveGuestUser(){
        User entity=new User();
        Long userId=iUserRepository.getNextAutoIncrement();
        entity.setId(userId);
        entity.setUserName("guestUser"+userId.toString());
        entity.setFirstName("guestUser"+userId.toString());
        entity.setLastName("guestUser"+userId.toString());
        entity.setPassWord("password"+userId.toString());
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grant = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        grant.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        super.save(entity);
        entity.setAuthorities(grant);
        Authentication authentication =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(entity, null, entity.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return entity;
    }
```

but when the request returns to the User Interface and i want to use application in another tab i get the 403 access denied .
what should i have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're actually authenticating with the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken:

```
 Authentication token =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(entity, null, entity.getAuthorities());
 Authentication authentication = this.authenticationProvider.authenticate(token);
```

See this related question for more detail: [How to manually set an authenticated user in Spring Security / SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664893/how-to-manually-set-an-authenticated-user-in-spring-security-springmvc)

---

Edit 1:
If you're using Spring Security, you presumably have a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` subclass already. You can wire in the `AuthenticationProvider` with something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   @Bean
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }
}
```

In your service layer, you can then autowire the bean, like this:

```
public class WhateverService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    ....
}
```

Comment: what do you mean about "this" , in my service layer i don't extend anything.

Comment: @Mohammad Mirzaeyan Please see edit 1 for example of acquiring `AuthenticationManager` from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: i use xml configuration , how do i add this config ?