# Spring security auto authorization for a given IP

Tags: java, web, spring-security

Is it possible in the Spring Security to (*well it is Java, of course possible, so quesiton is - is it possible in some relatively painless way*) automatically authorize all requests from local host (OK, some given IP) as a request that belongs to a given test user.

For instance in some filter - take all requests, check IP and if it comes from local host say something like spring.authorizeAs("user")

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672083/2932953) for the similar question may help you. Based on your requirements you build principal and set it manually to [Security Context](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html).

Comment: Looks like a solution, let's try it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case answer is following

```
@Component
public class LocalAuthFilter implements Filter {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService mng;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (("127.0.0.1".equals(req.getRemoteAddr())) &&
                ("anonymousUser".equals(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()))) {
            UserDetails userDetails = mng.loadUserByUsername("user"); //my test user
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails.getUsername(),
                    userDetails.getPassword(),
                    userDetails.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```